# Allow users to upload attachments to certain posts

Tags: images, taxonomy, attachments

I am hoping to get some possible solutions from you all :)

I have 330 regions set up as a taxonomy category.

Each region has it's own landing page displaying posts relating to that area.

I wanted a carousel to display user-uploaded images relating to each region also.

I can add a carousel which will pull post attachments, but how can I allow users to upload images to attach to the post?

I suppose another possible work around would be to allow users to add images and assign a region to the images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this might be with a plugin such as Gravity Forms, they allow you to create posts from a form, you can upload images too. They have an add on that helps you with this:
https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/advanced-post-creation/

You can also see a bit more on this information here: https://fewerthanthree.com/tutorial/using-gravity-forms-multi-file-uploads-when-creating-a-new-post/

There might be other options like Gravity Forms for Pods (if this is what you are using)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will take a look and see if it is suitable.